How to unlist a terminal buffer opened in a popup window?
I want to unlist a terminal buffer that I open in a popup window.
Here are my attempts:
var buf_no = term_start(&shell, {'term_name': 'foo', 'hidden': 1, 'term_finish': 'close'})
setbufvar(bufname(buf_no), 'buflisted', 0)

and
   var buf_no = term_start(os_shell, {'term_name': my_term_name, 'hidden': 1, 'term_finish': 'close'})
    win_execute(bufwinid(buf_no), 'setlocal nobuflisted')

but it does not work. I also check if there is some unlisted option in :h term_start() but it does not exists.

With the following code:
setbufvar(bufname(buf_no), 'buflisted', 0)

you are defining a buffer-local variable, b:buflisted with value 0, which is pointless because nothing is using it.
:help 'buflisted' is an option, not a variable. To change the value of an option, use the &option notation:
setbufvar(bufname(buf_no), '&buflisted', 0)

as per :help setbufvar():
[…]
Examples:
        :call setbufvar(1, "&mod", 1)
[…]

